# Inflate TextViews right of anohter TextView in a RelativeLayout not working Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, arraylist

I'm trying to inflate a layout inside a layout and add several TextViews inside it. To do so, I have an arrayList of the titles I want for each textview and also I have an array of TextViews of the same size of the arrayList. Thing is, this code only inflates ONE TextView (the last one in the arrayList).

```
 public void inflatePeriodGradeRightOf() {
    AcademicStatusController.getInstance(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "type="+instanceType+" id= "+instanceId);
    ArrayList<Item> periodsInfo = AcademicStatusController
            .getPeriodsInfo(instanceType, instanceId);

    RelativeLayout llDisplayData = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.help_relative_layout_for_periods);

    // Params to add some new rules
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams;
     relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     TextView tvtxt;
     TextView[] textViews = new TextView[periodsInfo.size()];
     int i = 0;

    for (Item info : periodsInfo) {
        // Inflate the view of the period
        View customView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_academic_status_period_layout, null);
        textViews[i] = new TextView(this);

        // Add the first textView and then add the others right of the last
        // one
        PeriodItem item = (PeriodItem) info;
        if (periodsInfo.get(0) == info) {
            // Set the text to the TextView.
            textViews[i].setText(item.getName());
            textViews[i].setId(i+1);
            llDisplayData.addView(customView);
        } else {
            // Set the text to the TextView.
            textViews[i].setText(item.getName())
            textViews[i].setId(i+1);
            relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textViews[i-1].getId());
                textViews[i].setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
            llDisplayData.addView(customView, relativeLayoutParams);
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

My "main" layout which is where I'm supposed to add the TextViews looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/carla123456"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/academic_status_banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/banner_team" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/academic_status_average"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_blue"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Promedio: ND"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/academic_status_subjects"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/academic_status_banner"
            android:background="@color/akdemia_blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Materias"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/academic_status_subjects_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/academic_status_subjects" >
        </ListView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/help_relative_layout_for_periods"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <!-- should not be larger than 320 to show content -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And what I am trying to achieve is this look:

[image]

But I can only get it to inflate just the last element in the arrayList.

Hope anyone can help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because the Id is always the same so you're adding the textviews all in top of the others. That's why you only see the last one, because it stayed on top of all the others.

Comment: I realised about that just now and actually changed the ids! let me update my code so you can see

Comment: @PedroOliveira done. I did that and I still get only the last textView in the array inflated

Comment: and after changing the ids then setText() is not working. :/

Comment: You shouldn't set id's on views like that. Id's must be an unique number. Refer to `View.generateViewId()`

Comment: Thanks! that wasn't the problem but it helped! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was trying to inflate each TextView instead of each RelativeLayout!

I have an array of Views and an array of TextViews, I inflate the first layout outside my loop to have a start point. Then for each one of the layouts and textViews inflate the view and find the TextView, set the text for the TextView (which in my case are the period names in the periodsInfo ArrayList), generate ids for the View and the TextView, set the params and add the view with such params.

One of the mistakes I made was using the SAME INSTANCE of LayoutParams for each layout, that doesn't work! You need to create a new instance of LayoutParams for each View you are going to add.

Here is the code to inflate a RelativeLayout right of another RelativeLayout.

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public void inflatePeriodGrade() {
        AcademicStatusController.getInstance(this);
        ArrayList<Item> periodsInfo = AcademicStatusController.getPeriodsInfo(
                instanceType, instanceId);

        // Find RelativeLayout where the period grade will be placed
        RelativeLayout llDisplayData = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.help_linear_layout_for_periods);

        View[] customViews = new View[periodsInfo.size()];
        TextView[] textViews = new TextView[periodsInfo.size()];
        //
        // Inflate the view of the period
        customViews[0] = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.activity_academic_status_period_layout, null);
        textViews[0] = (TextView) customViews[0]
                .findViewById(R.id.academic_status_grade);

        // Set the text to the TextView.
        textViews[0].setText(((PeriodItem) (periodsInfo.get(0))).getName());
        customViews[0].setId(View.generateViewId());
        textViews[0].setId(View.generateViewId());
        llDisplayData.addView(customViews[0]);

        int i = 1;
        for (Item item : periodsInfo) {

            PeriodItem period = (PeriodItem) item;

            if (periodsInfo.get(0) == period) {
                continue;
            }

            customViews[i] = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_academic_status_period_layout, null);
            textViews[i] = (TextView) customViews[i]
                    .findViewById(R.id.academic_status_grade);
            textViews[i].setText(period.getName());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams;
            newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
                    customViews[i - 1].getId());
            customViews[i].setId(View.generateViewId());
            textViews[i].setId(View.generateViewId());
            customViews[i].setLayoutParams(newParams);
            llDisplayData.addView(customViews[i], newParams);
            i++;
        }

    }
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but this is how I did it. I really hope this code helps somebody :)

Comment: Hello are you there ? @Carla Stabile